# Как вернуть json при вызове функции? SWIFT 4

Tags: json, ios, xcode, swift, swift4

Есть функция, которая должна возвращать сообщение о спарсенном json. 
Как можно вернуть это сообщение при вызове функции после получения json?

```
 func findEmail(_ email: String) -> EMessage
{
    let emailCrypto = crypto.encryptor(email as String)

    let urlString = "\(urlServer)searchUser/?email=\(emailCrypto)"

    var jsonParse: [String: Any]!

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString)
        else {
            return EMessage(message: "", type: 0)
    }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(60)
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(60)

    var session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url)
    {
        (data, response, error) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error
            {
                print("error = \(error)")
                return
            }
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do
        {
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else { return }
            jsonParse = json
            print(jsonParse)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()

    return EMessage(message: "", type: 0)
}
```

Заранее благодарю за любую обратную связь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предать в функцию completion block (closure) как параметр:

```
   func findEmail(_ email: String, completion: @escaping (EMessage?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
```

...

и json в Swift 4 можно парсить сразу в объект.